# Derive Ord with Quantified Constraints (forall a. Ord a => Ord (f a))

Tags: haskell, typeclass, derived-class, quantified-constraints

With quantified constraints I can derive `Eq (A f)` just fine? However, when I try to derive Ord (A f) it fails. I do not understand how to use quantified constraints when the constraint class has a superclass. How do I derive `Ord (A f)` and other classes that have superclasses?

```
> newtype A f = A (f Int)
> deriving instance (forall a. Eq a => Eq (f a)) => Eq (A f)
> deriving instance (forall a. Ord a => Ord (f a)) => Ord (A f)
<interactive>:3:1: error:
    • Could not deduce (Ord a)
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: forall a. Ord a => Ord (f a)
        bound by the instance declaration at <interactive>:3:1-61
      or from: Eq a bound by a quantified context at <interactive>:1:1
      Possible fix: add (Ord a) to the context of a quantified context
    • In the instance declaration for 'Ord (A f)'
```

PS. I have also examined [ghc proposals 0109-quantified-constraints](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0109-quantified-constraints.rst#superclasses). Using ghc 8.6.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `Eq` is a superclass of `Ord`, and the constraint `(forall a. Ord a => Ord (f a))` does not entail the superclass constraint `Eq (A f)` that's required to declare an `Ord (A f)` instance.

- We have `(forall a. Ord a => Ord (f a))`
- We need `Eq (A f)`, i.e., `(forall a. Eq a => Eq (f a))`, which is not implied by what we have.

Solution: add `(forall a. Eq a => Eq (f a))` to the `Ord` instance.

(I don't actually understand how the error message given by GHC relates to the problem.)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints, StandaloneDeriving, UndecidableInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

newtype A f = A (f Int)
deriving instance (forall a. Eq a => Eq (f a)) => Eq (A f)
deriving instance (forall a. Eq a => Eq (f a), forall a. Ord a => Ord (f a)) => Ord (A f)
```

Or a little more tidily:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, RankNTypes, KindSignatures, QuantifiedConstraints, StandaloneDeriving, UndecidableInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Kind (Constraint)

type Eq1 f = (forall a. Eq a => Eq (f a) :: Constraint)
type Ord1 f = (forall a. Ord a => Ord (f a) :: Constraint)  -- I also wanted to put Eq1 in here but was getting some impredicativity errors...

-----

newtype A f = A (f Int)
deriving instance Eq1 f => Eq (A f)
deriving instance (Eq1 f, Ord1 f) => Ord (A f)
```

Comment: I was so close with `deriving instance (forall a. (Eq a, Ord a) => (Eq (f a), Ord (f a))) => Ord (A f)`. Do you know why there is a difference?

Comment: That doesn't imply `forall a. Eq a => Eq (f a)` either. (viewed in terms of logic `(A /\ B) => (C /\ D)` does not imply `A => C`)

Comment: In fact what you wrote is equivalent to `forall a. Ord a => Ord (f a)`.